# Error sending messages from jetty to the queue(use camel)

Tags: apache-camel, jetty, activemq-classic, apache-servicemix

I use [servicemix](http://servicemix.apache.org/). I'm trying to send messages from jetty to the queue, but I get the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uACgA.png)
my blueprint:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
  <route>
    <from uri="jetty:http://localhost:8180/test"/>
    <to uri="activemq://events_test" /> 
  </route>
</camelContext>
```

if i use route from jetty to file - everything works as it should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Exchange pattern](http://camel.apache.org/exchange-pattern.html) of your route is InOut, so your jetty consumer waiting response from activemq producer. Response will appear if you have activemq consumer that will process your jetty request. If activemq producer shouldn't make response and you need just save request in queue use "inOnly" instead if "to", like this:

```
<inOnly uri="activemq://events_test" />
```